# What is the main difference between "light client" and "client" in sense of "functionality" and "capability"?

Tags: blockchain, light-clients, clients

What is the **main difference** between "`light client`" and "`client`" in sense of "**functionality** and **capability**" ?

I mean, what can a `client` does that a `light client` cannot ? (ex. *sending transactions?* *transaction confirmation?* etc)

Comment: Not necessarily an answer to your question, but a great starting point: [Light client protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol)